# mysql & maatkit: What kind of blocking will mk-table-checksum do?

Tags: mysql, unix, mysql-replication, maatkit

We have two MySQL servers set up with simple master-slave replication. We currently use all MyISAM tables, but may move to InnoDB in the future. Our largest tables are more then 2GB.

I would like to use the [mk-table-checksum](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-table-checksum.html) tools to run checksums on the tables, so that I can be sure that replication is working correctly.

The book [High Performance MySQL](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596003067) and this [mk-table-checksum tutorial](http://www.paragon-cs.com/tutorials/mk-table-checksum_tutorial.pdf) both recommend using `--sleep` and `--chunk-size` to help avoid database blocking.

My question is in regards to the 'blocking':

1. What sort of blocking might happen here? Is this simply referring to read locks on a table?
2. If I don't specify `--chunk-size`, some of these checksums take 4-5 minutes. Will the table be locked from writes at this time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just refers to read/write locks on tables.  Read locks if you're using the default checksum implementation built into MySQL; shared read locks if you're using --replicate, which does INSERT..SELECT statements.

Comment: And according to the documentation, mk-table-checksum will only INSERT data into the table specified by `--replicate`.

Comment: Thanks @Baron. Nice to have an answer from the person who wrote the tools!